# CSS calc() producing an odd result

Tags: css, less

I have the following CSS style on a fixed header element

```
width: calc(100% - 17px);
```

I'm working inside of SharePoint, and with the way SharePoint generates the scrollbar on the side, my header element (100% width) appears on top of the scrollbar. To account for this, I'm trying to remove the 17px for the scrollbar.

However, when the page renders, the width ends up being 83% and I'm not sure why. I unfortunately can't give you a link to the page in question because it's in our test environment. Any ideas why this would be producing a result of 83%?

EDIT: I should also mention I'm using LESS to write my styles. I just checked the compiled CSS document, and it is producing a final output of width: 83%.

Comment: You use it like this `header{width:calc(100% - 17px);}` ??

Comment: Is 100% == 100px by any chance? If not, what would happen if you do 100% - 30px?

Comment: It is not, 100% width is the width of the viewport/monitor. Oh, and that produced a result of 70%. If I do my CSS style in FireBug directly, it works fine, is seems to be LESS that is compiling it to 83%.

Comment: If you need to hardcode values to account for the scrollbar, you're doing something wrong. What about pages that don't have scroll, for the simplest example?

Comment: There isn't a page that doesn't have a scroll in our environment. When you work with SharePoint, it's a different beast.

Comment: Never using search? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bless%5d%20calc

Answer (score 2):

Please read this post. It has some workaround .
https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/974

Comment: This did it, thanks!
My code needed to be this:
 width: calc(~"100% - "17px);

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: While the answer is correct, the question should be voted to be closed in the first place ([less] already has *tens* of identical questions).